# How to interface Purify into Scons?

Tags: scons, purify, rational-purify

I have a Makefile that has various calls to scons.

```
scons "--jobs=8" -f SConstruct
```

The SCons command generates a line similar to the following:

```
g++ -o buildversion.o -c -c -g -fPIC buildversion.cc
```

How do you interface Purify into this mix?  I'm guessing that ultimately the line is suppose to look like

```
purify g++ -o buildversion.o -c -c -g -fPIC buildversion.cc
```

Comment: You might want to post your question to the SCons User mailing list ( scons-users@scons.org ). From previous threads there, I know that we have several people using Purify in SCons at their day jobs. They'll certainly know about all the "do and don't"s...

Comment: Unfortunately, scons.org appears to be a bust.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the environment, CC, CXX, SHCC, SHCXX, LINK, SHLINK depending on your particular scenario, appropriately, e.g.:

```
import os
env = Environment(ENV = {'PATH' : os.environ.get('PATH','')},
                  LINK = "purify g++")
```

Comment: You'll also need to make sure that purify is in the env['ENV']['PATH'], or you specify the full path to purify